# Prevent Wordpress from adding headers to outgoing requests

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I'm making a Wordpress plugin that makes HTTP requests to some third party API. Outside of Wordpress this works fine, but when using it on my Wordpress server, it seems to be adding a number of headers so that I now have duplicate headers, and the request fails.

Can anyone help me prevent Wordpress from adding the duplicate Content-Type and Content-Length headers?

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Content-Length: 20
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing a hard filter in the script making the call, making sure that all headers are in the CURL header array only once.